# How to setup FTP on xampp

Tags: ftp, xampp, filezilla

i want to make a server using xampp. i have already installed xampp and setting port 8080. php and mysql work fine but i can't access ftp from internet. Can you please suggest way how can I do this?

Answer (score 37):

XAMPP comes preloaded with the FileZilla FTP server. Here is how to setup the service, and create an account.

1. Enable the FileZilla FTP Service through the XAMPP Control Panel to make it startup automatically (check the checkbox next to filezilla to install the service). Then manually start the service.
2. Create an ftp account through the FileZilla Server Interface (its the essentially the filezilla control panel). There is a link to it Start Menu in XAMPP folder. Then go to Users->Add User->Stuff->Done.
3. Try connecting to the server (localhost, port 21).

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you

Comment: Very useful, Thanks for this knowledge @sayan

Comment: however based on Firewall configuration from the host machine, it requires to approve the FileZilla connecting to port (for external user port is 21)

Answer (score 10):

XAMPP for linux and mac comes with [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/). Make sure to start the service from XAMPP control panel -> manage servers.

Further complete instructions can be found at localhost XAMPP dashboard -> How-to guides -> Configure FTP Access. I have pasted them below :

1. Open a new Linux terminal and ensure you are logged in as root.
2. Create a new group named ftp. This group will contain those user accounts allowed to upload files via FTP.

> groupadd ftp

3. Add your account (in this example, susan) to the new group. Add other users if needed.

> usermod -a -G ftp susan

4. Change the ownership and permissions of the htdocs/ subdirectory of the XAMPP installation directory (typically, /opt/lampp) so that it is writable by the the new ftp group.

> cd /opt/lampp
>   chown root.ftp htdocs
>   chmod 775 htdocs

5. Ensure that proFTPD is running in the XAMPP control panel.

You can now transfer files to the XAMPP server using the steps below:

1. Start an FTP client like winSCP or FileZilla and enter connection details as below.

> If you’re connecting to the server from the same system, use
>   "127.0.0.1" as the host address. If you’re connecting from a different
>   system, use the network hostname or IP address of the XAMPP server.
>
> Use "21" as the port.
>
> Enter your Linux username and password as your FTP credentials.

Your FTP client should now connect to the server and enter the /opt/lampp/htdocs/ directory, which is the default Web server document root.

2. Transfer the file from your home directory to the server using normal FTP transfer conventions. If you’re using a graphical FTP client, you can usually drag and drop the file from one directory to the other. If you’re using a command-line FTP client, you can use the FTP PUT command.

Once the file is successfully transferred, you should be able to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I launched ubuntu Xampp server on AWS amazon.
And met the same problem with FTP, even though add user to group ftp SFTP and set permissions, owner group of htdocs folder. 
Finally find the reason in inbound rules in security group, added All TCP, 0 - 65535 rule(0.0.0.0/0,::/0) , then working right!

Answer (score 0):

On XAMPP click "**Start**" and after "**Admin**".

Login to localhost (127.0.0.1) without password, with second port, not with 21.

Add users and passwords, change your settings. Quit.