# How to install WordPress Theme or Plugin on XAMPP-VM (Mac OS)

Tags: wordpress, xampp-vm

I have installed WordPress on XAMPP-VM (don't use addon).
But when I add new Theme or Plugin, I need to enter FTP credentials and I don't know what username/password I should to use.

[image: install WordPress plugin]

I can connect with account `daemon/xampp` but must change the permission of `htdocs` folder to `777`.

What FTP account I can use that I don't need to change permission to `777`?

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

[How to setup FTP on xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707729/how-to-setup-ftp-on-xampp)

Alternatively, do note that you don't need to change the permissions on the htdocs folder proper, you can do it in on the **plugins** and **themes** folders in wp-content. See:

[Wordpress FTP connection setting for localhost to upload and install WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788193/wordpress-ftp-connection-setting-for-localhost-to-upload-and-install-woocommerce)

Comment: I'm using XAMPP-VM on Mac, and it only has service ProFTPD (no config button).

Answer (score 1):

Please use your system(means laptop/desktop) username and password here

Comment: it's not working. I'm using XAMPP-VM on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the permission issue, you can avoid it by writing the following code into your `wp-config.php` :

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: you are right. it worked.